# JQgrid: During modal initialization, how would I determine what model is being created (add/edit)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I've got a case when i need to provide a different source id based on if the user is editing or adding. My initial idea was to set a hidden field's value using the beforeShowForm hook, but it seems that the components get initialized before the hook's function is called. Thus I'm unable to determine what model is being created at that stage of initialization.

**[A]**

```
//initLoadNoEdit gets called... (At this point I need to know if its going to be an add/edit.)
initLoadNoEdit = function (elem) {
    if ($('#curr_action').val() == 'add') {
        createLoadNumberWidget(elem, "#Date", 'some_url');
    } else {
        createLoadNumberWidget(elem, "#modal_date", 'some_url');
    }
}

var colModel = [
        { name: 'FI_ID', index: 'FI_ID', key: true, editable: false, hidden: true, search: false },     
        { name: 'LILBP_ID', index: 'LILBP_ID', editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { dataInit: initLoadNoEdit } }
];

//...before this gets called
var addBeforeShowOptions = function (form) {
    $('#curr_action').val('add');
}

//...or this
var editBeforeShowOptions = function (form) {
    $('#curr_action').val('edit');
}
```

I then tried to add an on click event on the button add/edit click of the grid, i tried .live(), .delegate(), and just a normal .click(). but had no results, the pager renders as follows..

**[B]**

```
   <td id="pager_left" align="left">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ui-pg-table navtable" style="float:left;table-layout:auto;">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Add new row" id="add_theGrid">
              <div class="ui-pg-div">
                 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
              </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
```

so i tried something like

```
 $('#add_theGrid').live('click', function () { $('#curr_action').val('add'); }); 

 //and

 $('#pager_left').delegate('#add_theGrid','click', function () { $('#curr_action').val('add'); });
```

that being said... i don't think that passing a value into a variable is the best way to go about this, as I'm sure there should be a way of me to determine from the modal, what type of modal it is? I just haven't been able to find it yet..

Comment: Are you using the navigator?

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator

Can you submit a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The form's title text should be different between Add and Edit:</strike>

```
jQuery('.ui-jqdialog-title').text()
```

Then you can check the front of it for "Add" or "Edit". Obviously this is not an ideal solution but it is a simple way to use data that is already on the form. I think it is a bit of a hack, though.

---

A better solution is to use the `jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData` event that is fired before `dataInit`. This is one of the new [triggered events in 4.3.2](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2). Documentation is a bit sparse but if you look at the code in `grid.formedit.js` you can see that a `frmoper` parameter is passed which indicates whether the form is in "add" or "edit" mode (I added line breaks to make it easier to read):

```
showFrm = $($t).triggerHandler(
            "jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData", 
            [$("#"+frmgr), frmoper]);
```

According to the jQuery docs for [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), the second parameter is a list of extra parameters. You can then use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to add your own event handler:

```
grid.bind('jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData', function(e, form, oper) {
    alert ("Before dataInit, operation is " + oper);
    // Your code here...
});
```

Does that help?

Comment: I'll be back at work in about an hour or 2. But as for the title. I tried that. Seems like the controls get initialized before the title gets set. I'll check this event out though "jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData" and let you know.

Comment: Great answer! Solved my problem in less than 5 seconds!

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped you out! I'll update my answer to remove the part about the title.

Comment: @RohanBüchner - By the way, I noticed a case where the `oper` field did not appear to be set in the `jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData` event when a form is reopened. If this is a problem for you, you might want to look at this fix that just got merged into jqGrid (a simple one liner): https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/351

Comment: I just manually appended the fix. (Issue didn't pop up during testing... but I'd rather be safe than sorry)
Thanks again! :)

Comment: You're welcome, just noticed that and wanted to try and prevent any future problems :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the jqGrid Navigator you could easily do that with the addfunc, editfunc and delfunc options. This way you could assignate a custom function on every actions and for inline editing well you know already it's not add because you are inline.

check :
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator

if you need an example please post a jsfiddle i could edit.