# Using multiple jquery autocomplete datasources for a single textbox 

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I wanted to use multiple jQuery autocomplete for a single textbox, where datasources are different for every autocomplete. I have two datasources, one that should be used on typing @ in textbox, and another used after typing > in textbox.

For example:

```
// Datasource1 
country = {[name:india, displayname:GreatIndia] [name:china , displayName:BigChina] [name:usa , displayname:unitedstates }

// Datasource2 
colors = {[colorName:Red , Statistic:Dark] [colorName:blue , Statistic:calm] [colorName:Green , Statistic:Cool] }
```

If I type "@In" it show India , GreatIndia other way around if I type "@Gr" it also has to show India , GreatIndia in textbox.

Similarly for same text box if I type ">bl" it should show blue,calm

Comment: This could easily be done using a single `autocomplete` instance and a custom source function.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect answer, but it can be a starting point.

I haven't tested this, but you could possibly do something like this of the url?

```
  $("#id").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                   $.ajax({
                     url: function(request.term),
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: {
                          filter: request.term
                     },
                     success: function (data) {
                         //do something
                     }
             })
             },
              select: function (event, ui) {
                  //do something            
             }
});    

function(term)
{
   //implement logic that  
   //returns a string url
}
```

*(I had a [somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579828/jqgrid-during-modal-initialization-how-would-i-determine-what-model-is-being-c) scenario the other day (your's being different in the sense that the url must be set dynamically using the component itself))*